# How do I Display results that match the users input from a JOptionPane in linked list?

Tags: java

I have created an object of Type Car with make, model, year, mileage as variables,

The program reads from a file through and the displays through linked lists a sorted and an unsorted version. I have created a class to add values to the object. How should I modify the code so that when the users enter an input let say Ford, the GUI displays only the values of Cars named Ford? that has a and object named

Here is a link to what the GUI displays I want to display in the sorted list only values of the same input as the user entered.

[image: GUI]

```
String menuName = event.getActionCommand();`

String input;

   // if clicked "Add," prompt user for input dialog
   // and if valid RN, add it to each list,
   // then display the list to reflect the addition
   if (menuName.equals("Add")) {
   input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a Car to add:");
   try {
       StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(input);

       Car cr = new Car(st.nextToken(), st.nextToken(), Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()),
               Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
       crGUI.inOrder.add(cr);
       crGUI.sorted.add(cr);
   } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Illegal Car: " + input);
       System.out.println("Illegal Car: " + input);
   }
   crGUI.displaySorted();
   crGUI.displayUnsorted();
}   } }
```

Answer (score 0):

if crGui.displaySorted() can check what type of make it is. If you pass it some sort of string maybe?

Answer (score 0):

The best way for your requirement could be using hashmaps with 'make' as a key and a list of objects as value.

```
Hashmap<string,List<Car>> carGui = new Hashmap<string,List<Car>>();
```

With the code provided, i could not understand the whole scope of carGui. May be this can give you an idea.